# CQ5 ECMA script get reference to service

Tags: javascript, aem

I've got a service running on my CQ5 istance and I want to invoke its method from a workflow. 
My question is, how can I get the reference of a service from a ECMA script?

I've already tried:

```
var myService= sling.getService(Packages.com.my.package.MyService.class);
```

but I get a "missing name after . operator" and

```
var myService= sling.getService(Packages.com.my.package.MyService);
```

but I get null reference.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how that works in CQ workflow ECMA scripts but in plain Sling server-side Javascript the `sling.getService(Packages.com.example.MyServiceInterface)` syntax is correct.

Make sure the OSGi console at `/system/console/services` shows an active service with the `MyServiceInterface`.

Comment: Yes it actually works fine. My error was not using the interface! Thanks for the answer you give me the hint!

Comment: Just to say that `null` would be the expected response if the Service is unavailable, rather than an error — i.e. you should handle a `null` case in your code also, as Services can come & go during your application's lifecycle.